# Can i make percentage based sorting in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, percentage

For example: I have several user rows, and each user has either 0% boost or 10% boost to be chosen. So when I sort the rows, user with 10% has 10% more chance to be sorted on top of others than other users. Is it possible in sql? If not, what should I use to make this kind of searching algorithm?

Comment: How are users sorted if their boost is the same?

Answer (score 0):

To `boost` greater chance of ordering earlier, order by `random()` multiplied by `1 + boost` as follows (assuming `boost` is a floating point number from 0-1):

```
select *
from mytable
order by random() * (1 + boost) desc
```

If `boost` is a percentage (a number from 0-100):

```
select *
from mytable
order by random() * (100 + boost) desc
```